# Flutter Local Schedule Notification not working

Tags: flutter, android-notifications

Im trying to schedule a local notification in my flutter app but it doesnt show, it doesnt trigger any error or exception, just doesnt appear in my screen

I have tried to debbug the app but it didnt help with anything, chatGPT4 didnt help me either.

NotificationService:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:prj_unyclub/constants/appRoutes.dart';
import 'package:prj_unyclub/main.dart';
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

class CustomNotification {
  final int id;
  final String? title;
  final String? body;
  final String? payload;

  CustomNotification({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.body,
    required this.payload,
  });
}

class NotificationService {
  NotificationService();

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> init() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher");

    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse response) {
        if (response.payload != null) {
          selectNotificationStream.add(response.payload);
        }
      },
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: _onSelectedNotification,
    );

    selectNotificationStream.stream.listen((String? payload) {
      if (payload != null && payload.isNotEmpty) {
        AppRoutes.navigatorKey!.currentState!.pushNamed(payload);
      }
    });
  }

  static _onSelectedNotification(NotificationResponse? response) async {
    if (response?.payload != null) {
      String payloadCoded = response!.payload!;
      var payload = jsonDecode(payloadCoded);
      print('payload: ${payload['route']}');
      selectNotificationStream.add(payload['route']);
    }
  }

  Future<void> showNotification(CustomNotification notification) async {
    // Verifica se payload é nulo antes de prosseguir
    if (notification.payload == null) return;

    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'unyclubNotification',
      'Unyclub',
      channelDescription: "Este canal é para todas as notificaçõs do unyclub",
      importance: Importance.high,
      priority: Priority.max,
    );

    const DarwinNotificationDetails iOSDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails(
      presentBadge: true,
      presentAlert: true,
      presentBanner: true,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.id,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      const NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iOSDetails),
      payload: notification.payload,
    );
  }

  Future<void> scheduleNotification(
    CustomNotification notification,
    DateTime scheduledDate,
  ) async {
    // Verifica se payload é nulo antes de prosseguir
    if (notification.payload == null) return;

    // Detalhes da notificação para Android
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'unyclubNotification',
      'Unyclub',
      channelDescription: "Este canal é para todas as notificações do unyclub",
      importance: Importance.high,
      priority: Priority.max,
    );

    // Detalhes da notificação para iOS
    const DarwinNotificationDetails iOSDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails(
      presentBadge: true,
      presentAlert: true,
      presentSound: true,
    );

    // Configuração de detalhes de notificação para ambas as plataformas
    NotificationDetails platformDetails =
        const NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iOSDetails);

    // Agendando a notificação
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      notification.id,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      tz.TZDateTime.from(
        scheduledDate,
        tz.local,
      ), // Assegura-se de que a data agendada está no fuso horário local
      platformDetails,
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
      payload: notification.payload,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }

  checkForNotifications() async {
    final details =
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    if (details != null && details.didNotificationLaunchApp) {
      _onSelectedNotification(details.notificationResponse);
    }
  }
}
```

Main:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Permission.notification.isDenied.then((value) {
    if (value) {
      Permission.notification.request();
    }
  });
  await Permission.scheduleExactAlarm.isDenied.then((value) {
    if (value) {
      Permission.scheduleExactAlarm.request();
    }
  });
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  NotificationService notificationService = NotificationService();
  await notificationService.init();
  FirebaseMessagingService firebaseMessagingService =
      FirebaseMessagingService();
  firebaseMessagingService.initialize();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  final String timeZoneName = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
  tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

ScheduleMethod

```
Future<void> scheduleMeetingsNotifications() async {
    //? Carregando as reuniões
    MeetingsController controller = MeetingsController(context: context);
    List<Meetings> meetingsList = [];
    await controller.loadMeetings("1").then((value) {
      setState(() {
        meetingsList = controller.getMeetingsList;
      });
    });

    //? Pegando a data da ultima reunião
    Meetings meeting = meetingsList[0];
    DateTime notificationDate = DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        .parse(meeting.dtMeeting!)
        .subtract(const Duration(hours: 12));

    //? Agendando a Notificação
    NotificationService notificationService = NotificationService();
    DateTime time = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(seconds: 10));
    print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ $time @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
    notificationService.scheduleNotification(
      CustomNotification(
        id: int.parse(meeting.id!),
        title: meeting.topic!,
        body: "A reunião começa",
        payload: jsonEncode({"route": AppRoutes.meetingsScreen}),
      ),
      time,
    );
  }
```

Im trying to send the notification 10 seconds after the method just for testing porpouses, also tried to send the notification 30 seconds and 1 minute after.

I have asked for the notifications permission in the main method but also put it in my android manifest since im testing in a android emulator